# In Community, navigate from one aura component to another

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, aura, navigation

I have a community page where I need to navigate from one aura component to another (on the same page, no full page redraw).
I start in "FirstComponent.cmp" and click a button which should result in displaying SecondComponent.cmp

FirstComponent.cmp

```
<aura:component controller="FMZ_SuiteServices"
  implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes"
  access="global">

  <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>

<lightning:button label="Add Tour" onclick="{!c.handleAddTour}"></lightning:button>

</aura>
```

firstComponentController.js (segment)

```
handleAddTour: function (component, event, helper) {

component.find("navService").navigate({
  type: 'standard__component',
  attributes: {
    componentName: "c__SecondComponent"
  },
  state: {}
});
```

},

SecondComponent.cmp

```
    <aura:component controller="FMZ_TourServices"
implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,force:lightningQuickAction,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:isUrlAddressable"
access="global">Welcome To The Second Component</aura>
```

Would appreciate any help with what I am missing! TIA

Comment: +1. The same code work in lightning but not in communities.

Answer (score 0):

you set wrong  `page reference Type`, i would recommend to go through [pageReference Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm) once again. for communities you should be use `comm__namedPage` not `standard__component` and check `pageName` attribute too.   your code should like below.

```
    handleAddTour: function (component, event, helper) {

      component.find("navService").navigate({
         type: 'comm__namedPage',
         attributes: {
          pageName: "custom community page"  // for page name you have to create custom page in your community then drag 2nd component in to that page
          },
          state: {}
         });
   },
```